# MySQL - Join tables and add if specific value exists

Tags: mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am posting this question while there may be an answer somewhere, I am having trouble with my search terminology. My initial query below grabs the correct number of results I need.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'video'
AND post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY 'post_date'
```

My problem is that I have a custom field value in a different table which exists on some of the posts but not all of them. If the field value exists, I want the information to show up in another column. When I do a normal JOIN, I end up with too many results because I am not sure how to filter out "if the value exists" query.

Basically I want to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'video'
AND post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY 'post_date'
```

Then from table two which is called wp_postmeta
    AND IF meta_key = 'source'
    FROM wp_postmeta

** THEN ADD two more columns from the 2nd table **

My biggest issue is that the meta_key column in my 2nd table has many values which are tied to the same ID. So if I do a regular simple JOIN, I come back with too many rows.

I'm sorry if I can't describe this any more clear but if someone knows what I am trying to accomplish, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have figured this out that I need to add a LEFT JOIN to accomplish what I wanted. Thanks and sorry for taking up your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out that I need to add a LEFT JOIN to accomplish what I wanted. Thanks and sorry for taking up your time

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts A
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta B
ON A.ID = B.post_id
AND B.meta_key = 'sources' 
WHERE A.post_type = 'video'
AND A.post_status = 'publish'
```